# Passing an object from knockout to opener window

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have the following scenario in my site, a page (opener) can open a "Settings" page, where you can change settings, save and close in order to continue in the opener page.

The problem is that right now the settings aren't passed along from the settings page to the opener page.

So I added this in the saveSettings function:

```
    saveSettings: function () {  
    var jsonObj = ko.mapping.toJSON(this.ViewModel);
    SD.CORP.WS.HedgingEffectivenessSettingsService.SetHedgingEffectivenessSettings(userID, companyID, selectedProductID, jsonObj, saveSettingsOnSucc, saveSettingsOnFaild);
```

This is an example of what I've added:

```
    var settings = JSON.parse(jsonObj);


    window.opener.requestParameters.ReportSetting.ProspectiveTestSettings = settings.ProspectiveTestSettings;
}
```

But when I try to use it on the opener these objects are empty, if I try to JSON.stringify the object I get a "The interface is unknown" error.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I found out in the meanwhile that the actual problem was that I assigned an object from the settings window to the opener window, so when I closed the settings window, the object no longer existed.

I fixed it by adding a function on the opener script so that I can call it from the settings page and then use $.extend in order to create a deep copy on the opener page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use window.postMessage to send the settings from the settings window to the opener. Article on how to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Opener:

```
window.addEventListner('message', function(event) {
    var settings = JSON.parse(event.data)
}, false);
```

Settings window:

```
window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

Comment: I've updated about a solution I've made. It seems like your solution is even better and better structured! so thanks. just one thing: I think that the object should be deep copied in order to remove coupling to the other window...